# Hidden public property in WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am writing a custom control in WPF that works in this way: user sets some property which type is some class. Then, the control examines this object and generates some collection, which is to be displayed in UI via data binding.

In order for data binding to work, this collection should be a public property, but for the sake of incapsulation I do not want it to be public.

What is the best practice in such a situation?

Comment: Can't you just make it `private`? Or make the `set` to be `private`? Or even better, use a `ReadOnlyCollection`, and make that `set` to be `private`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Browsable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute to hide property from property grid and the [EditorBrowsable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to hide it from the XAML\CS editor. Or you can override the [OnApplyTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) method and assign your property value to the target element. You can get target element using the [GetTemplateChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild(v=vs.110).aspx) method.